# In C how does a character work

Tags: c, char, ascii

In the program I have given below we take `j` as a character.
We take `j=1` but the ascii value of 1 is 49. So why the answer is 15? Is `j` working as an integer?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char j;

    for(j=1 ; j <=5 ; j++)
    {
        printf("-%c\n",j);
        i=i+j;
        printf("%c\n",i);
    }

    printf("%d",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C, `char` is a NUMERICAL variable 1 Byte long (8 bits). An `unsigned char` has the possible values 0 to 255 and a `signed char` -127 to +127. The value `char a = 1` is equal to `1` NOT to `'1'`.

Answer (score 2):

In the loop there is calculated the sum of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 that indeed is equal to 15.

In this expression

```
i=i+j;
```

operand `j` is converted to type `int` due to the integer promotions and the result of type `int` is stored in the variable `i`.

In this statement

```
printf("%d",i);
```

this result as an integer value is outputed.

If you want to deal with character values '1', '2' and so on you could write the loop like

```
for ( j = '1' ; j <= '5' ; j++ )
```

and if the ASCII coding is used then variable `i` will contain the sum of the values 49, 50, 51, 52, 53.

Comment: But how J is converting into int? . why computer is not calculating the value of j=1 as 49 ? ?

Comment: @ShahirRahman If you write j = '1'; then j indeed will stored as value 49 in the ASCII coding is used. However you explicitly assigned it with value 1 instead of '1'.

Comment: @ShahirRahman You could write the loop like     for(j='1' ; j <='5' ; j++)

Comment: :D ... NOW i get it !! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
```

declares `i` as `int`

```
char j;
```

declares `j` as `char`

```
for(j=1 ; j <=5 ; j++)
```

initializes `j` with an integer, to initialize it with the ASCII value for *1*, 49 you could use

```
for(j='1' ; j <= '1' + 5 ; j++)
```

but I don't understand what your ultimate goal is and how this would work for you?

```
    printf("%c\n",i);
```

Is outputting a `char`; despite `i` being an `int`.

```
printf("%d",i);
```

Is outputting an `int`.

The difference now is the first will exceed the ASCII range of 0-127 on the third iteration, so I would suggest you change it the latter form (of `%d`).

Comment: Its a bit clear to me now .
i hv a  little bit confusion though . 
well my doubt is if i run this code the ouput is 15 . bt i was thiinking why it is not calculating 49+50+51 ... like this as J is a character here !!
    and the ascii value of J=1 is 49 to computer !!